# AVAudioPlayer seek performance is not good

Tags: iphone

We are a developing an application which is supposed to play long audio files. duration of audio file can be upto 23 hours...

we are trying to use this AVAuidoPlayer for this purpose. To perform fast forward we are setting CurrentTime property of AVAudioPlayer. if the forward duration is just few minutes or even upto 20 minutes everything works fine. But if we try to jump by say 2 hours time then setCurrentTime call on the player take too long time ( almost 30-40 seconds). This is not acceptable behavior.

please let me know if anybody managed to successfully use AVAudioPlayer setCurrentTime property to jump long durations (say 2 hours)

Comment: Its been very long I posted this question, just wanted to updated.

I could not find any method to optimize this in AVAudioPlayer (Nothing exists probably). So I removed AVAudio player from my code and instead using a Audio Streamer built using the AudioQueues

Answer (score 1):

What is the file format of your file?

I had this problem with MP3, it worked better with AAC.

Comment: yes, im also dealing with mp3 files. In my case I cannot switch to AAC, server gives me mp3 files.

Anyways, Thanks for your post